ConTeXT : unable to run it
I am new to ConTeXt (but user of LaTeX).
Whatever IDE I use, I get the error message :
..."formats/luametatex/cont-en.fmt' failed with bad 'version id' data".
My current version of ConTeXT is the  2024.02.27 one.
I have tried,without success to rebuild the cont-en.fmt format file by running the command luametatex --ini cont-en).
Indeed, I am lost...
Thanks a lot for your help.

What is an EDI, is that the sameas an IDE? Did you try the terminal/command line as well? It probably won't make a difference but it is always a good idea to test 'clean', by directly running the command yourself from a terminal.

How did you install it? Does it run from the terminal?

To run ConTeXt you use context <filename> on the command line. When there is no format file ConTeXt tries to create it itself but you can also create it by hand with context --make.

Thank you Wolfgang. I'va just tried it, but always the message "fatal format error, loading file 'C:/ConTeXT/context-win64/tex/texmf-cache/luametatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luametatex/cont-en.fmt' failed with bad 'version id' data, remake the format"

You can try to wipe the cache with the format file and everything else and rebuild it with the three step a) mtxrun --script cache --erase b) mtxrun --generate and c) context --make. When this still fails try to install ConTeXt in your user directory and try it again.

Thank you. I've tried it, but failed : always the error message "fatal format error, loading file 'C:/ConTeXT/context-win64/tex/texmf-cache/luametatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luametatex/cont-en.fmt' failed with bad 'version id' data, remake the format"

Do you have the same problem when you install ConTeXt in your home directory (C:\Users\...)?

Wolfgang  It's a different error message : "input file './MonTest.tex' is not found, quitting"

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation#Installation Do any of those instructions help?
